# How can I achieve Python in colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, keras-layer

I want to try the process defined in

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSzou5zRwNQ
```

to examine Deep Learning House Price Prediction.

But in my colab there isn't new python 3 notebook available as presented in this video.

My screen is as follows:

[image: colab screenshot]

Accordingly the following codes failed with following error massage

[image: colab error massage]

Could anyone help me to solve that

Thanks in advance

Comment: By default, colab uses python3 to create notebooks, and you must import `Sequential` not `sequential`

Comment: grateful ... so thanks ....that's work

Answer (score 0):

that's fine
i solve as suggested in comments

here is the right Python Implementation

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np # working with arrays
```